# Vaadin : Widget set is not getting loaded.

Tags: java, spring, gwt, vaadin

I was able to integrate a Vaadin module into our Spring based application. After integration I wanted to run a demo of gantt-charts which is an add-on for Vaadin and found it on github [here](https://github.com/tltv/gantt). Inside the folder, there is a demo project. All is fine, except I am having a problem with widgetsets.

Screenshot of the problem :

[image: Widget set not loaded]

Also I get a non-serializable error :

```
Nov 18, 2015 3:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager startInternal
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.journaldev.spring.Vaadin.Util$5
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
```

UI code :

```
@Theme("demo")
@SpringUI
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {


    @WebServlet(value = "/testvaadin", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class, widgetset = "org.tltv.gantt.demo.DemoWidgetSet")
    public static class Servlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {
    }

// Code for gaant-chart taken from demo, code too big and not important //for error
// Pastebin link : http://pastebin.com/mi1ZhH30
}
```

POM.xml :

vaadin-addons
        http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons

```
<!--- Vaadin dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tltv.gantt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gantt-addon</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml :

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadin-spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometDServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>timeout</param-name>
            <param-value>300000</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
```

What am I doing wrong? Kindly let me know. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Have you recompiled the widgetset? (When adding client side components you have to do it)

Comment: @AndréSchild : How do I do that? When i give maven vaadin:compile it says, goal compile not found. I don't have that file DemoWidgetSet.xml and I copied it from the gaant-demo project, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run **mvn clean install** to compile the widgetset. If you don't want to use command line, right click in your proyect, **Run As > Maven install**.

You can also compile your widgetset in eclipse. Open your widgetset file and click in the "gear" symbol in the eclipse menu.

Comment: `mvn clean install` removes the client-side js codes, if they exist, but does not regenerate them. `mvn vaadin:compile` is what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

You need the vaadin client-compiler to be able to compile your widgetset. Add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And run `mvn vaadin:compile` to compile your client-side widgetset.

EDIT: Also have a file called `com.journaldev.demoset.gwt.xml` in your build path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />

    <add-linker name="xsiframe" />

    <inherits name="org.tltv.gantt.WidgetSet" />

</module>
```

and change your annotated servlet to read the widgetset from that file.

```
@WebServlet(value = "/testvaadin", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class, widgetset = "com.journaldev.demoset")
public static class Servlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {
}
```

With that, you are defining your own widgetset which includes the one defined in the gantt chart project.

Comment: Added, no change. Also issued mvn vaadin:update-widgetset. I get an error : INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.journaldev.demoset.gwt.xml/com.journaldev.demoset.gwt.xml.nocache.js] not found

Comment: Interesting, your servlet annotation asks for `org.tltv.gantt.demo.DemoWidgetSet` but maven tries to compile `com.journaldev.demoset.gwt.xml`. Do you have this file in your build path? If so, change your servlet annotation to read from `com.journaldev.demoset` and then include `rg.tltv.gantt.demo.DemoWidgetSet` in your xml file. Something like the one I mentioned in the reply.

Comment: How to compile with Gradle?